# Running GWT DevMode offline

Tags: java, gwt

for some reason i do not have internet connection when debugging my GWT project.
is internet connection necessary when run a GWT project in DevMode? and can I run my code without internet connection?

when i run the project browser displays:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require internet connection for GWT application development once you have installed all the prerequisites as described in below links.

Please have a look at below links and follow it step by step.

- [GWT Project setup](http://www.gwtproject.org/usingeclipse.html#running)
- [GWT getting started](http://www.gwtproject.org/gettingstarted.html)

Comment: the problem was installing gwt-dev-plugin. I upgrade my Chrome browser and the gwt plugin and now without internet connection i can run the project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You dont need a Internet connection for developing a GWT Application if you have all dependencies like from maven on your PC and you are developing on your localhost machine.
You can also debug the gwt-application without a Internet connection.

Comment: thanks for reply. but when i run project (using Intellij) browser try to connect to googlecode? how can i disable this?

Comment: You probably have it in your code or you do not have all the dependencies downloaded locally.

Comment: @mareckmareck i use maven and all dependencies added correctly.

Comment: Is there maybe a other dependency in your project which is connecting to googlecode?

Comment: If you dont have the dev mode plugin installed, trying to run dev mode will redirect you to go and get it - you can't download and install the plugin if you aren't online.

Comment: @ColinAlworth yes i install the plugin and again it shows me install plugin page...